# Properties of convolution for time discrete signals: Why is signal convolution with "delta" signal true?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, discrete-time

I'm trying to explain to myself why this property is true;
[signal convolution with "delta" function = signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHdsa.png) However, I don't understand why? I know that the Diracs delta function has a value 1 at zero, and zero at the rest of the values. Therefore, for instance, if I had '

x[5] * delta[5], then that should equal 0 but what if x[5] equals 10, then the property does not hold?

Comment: Please tell me if not clear, English is not my first language.

Comment: It seems that you need to remind yourself what the convolution of two sequences actually is! The expression “$x[5] * \delta[5]$” is quite meaningless. (The star does *not* mean multiplication in this context.)

Comment: A convolution works on functions or sequences and outputs functions or sequences, not values. (x*delta)[5] is meaningful but x[5]*delta[5] is not.